# Need to render/display images according to custom layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

[image]

**Can anybody tell me how can I achieve this layout?.**

Any example or tutorial related to this?
 I need to render flags of country with name according to following layout. I also need paging as well for this. Images are already present in local folder. 
I googled but couldn't find good example.I am newbie in android

**- I am using Android studio 1.3.2**

Comment: read about cardview. There are a lot of tutorials

Comment: first of all read about the `RecyclerView`... and then come back with a question that includes what you've tried so far.